# Spartacus Change Language to User Default Language while Login

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am trying to set the language from the Session language set for Customer in CX. This value is set during the login through CDC.

How can  I send the same language in all the requests to the Backend OCC call from Spartacus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Language settings are set in `src/app/app.module.ts`

For example:

```
B2cStorefrontModule.withConfig({
  ...
  context: {
    currency: ['USD'],
    language: ['en'],
    baseSite: ['electronics-spa'],
  },
  ...
}),
```